# Apply condition for a particular group: SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Currently I have to provide a report in BigQuery for Google Analytics of a format:

*ClientID, SessionID, Source, Medium SessionNumber*

So, the outcome has to be the table where for every *ClientID, SessionNumber* contains ordinal of an event occurred sorted by date

**The problem is** during one session a conversion occurs. So *SessionNumber* values for the particular *ClientID* do not end at the event where conversion occurs. 
[*For example, there are 30 events in a ClientID = 1, and conversion occurs at 15-th event (ordinal from SessionNumber)*]

**My question is** how to delete all the data in a table after the ordinal in  *SessionNumber* when conversion occurs? 
So it would become possible to see when the lastclick occurred and and see the Assisted Conversion? 
How to apply a condition for a particular group of data (for every *client ID*, in this case - REMEMBER that, here, for every *ClientID* we have a particular number of events and corresponding ordinals)

Example:

```
Client ID | SessionID | Source | Medium | SesionNumber | Goal Achieved (1 if yes) 
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            1 |                       0
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            2 |                       0
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            3 |                       1
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            4 |                       0
        2 |        234|  ...       ...             ...                       ...
       ...         ...   ...       ...             ...                       ...
```

So, I have to get rid of all the rows after the *SessionNumber* when conversion occurred inside of each *ClientID* *(Conversion occurs after the goal is achieved - I have already created such code)*. Is there any Syntax for standard SQL which would allow to create such condition for **every ClientID** ?

**The thing is that inside one session conversion may occur and after that user can do other things as well, but I only need records from the start of the session until conversion occurs**

I would like to return the table (from the example):

```
Client ID | SessionID | Source | Medium | SesionNumber | Goal Achieved (1 if yes) 
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            1 |                       0
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            2 |                       0
        1 |        456| google |   cpc  |            3 |                       1
        2 |        234|  ...       ...             ...                       ...
       ...         ...   ...       ...             ...                       ...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your sample, data desired output and rules by adding them to the question?

Comment: I am still trying to understand what you want to achieve, do you want to select the values when the SessionNumber is equal to 15? Can you explain what is a "conversion" occurrence?

Comment: @alexandre-moraes Big Query takes the data from Google Analytics. And the conversion, in GA, is the event when our set goal is achieved. In my code, I have already chosen only such clients whose sessions contain conversion in WHERE clause. For example, conversion may happen when the goal in GA is set such way, so that general expression of the particular type is found in Java Script. So, in my WHERE clause I have included these general expressions for the clients' return

Comment: @alexandre-moraes If you look at my table from the question, I'd like to get the values {0, 0, 1} in the column _Goal Achieved_ without the last {0} for the _ClientID_ = 1. So, for every _ClientID_ get only all zeroes before 1 and 1 itself, without all the zeroes following 1

Comment: So instead of deleting rows wouldn't be better to create a new view or table when the condition is met ? I understood that you already have the filter to extract the data you aim, right? ( to get the data you said in your previous comment)

Comment: @alexandre-moraes the thing is I don't know how to form such a condition. I didn't say right - I don't want to delete these rows. I just want to return the table of the form:
(I edited the question)